# Orchard 'Layers' seem an odd concept when compared to other Asp.net based CMSs

Tags: orchardcms

We're busy investigating Orchard CMS as an alternative to existing Asp.net based CMS systems that we use. We came across Orchard, installed it and started on the tutorials.

The one part that confuses me is layers. We don't have anything in other CMSs that seem to compare to this.

What we're used to, is having a couple of master pages (or templates) then you create a new page and choose a template for the page and add widgets to the various container areas.

Here you seem to create multiple layers and apply them based on URL rules (or perhaps others too).

Questions:

1. Assuming these are layers, as in Photoshop layers, it would seem that you're adding widgets to layers from the bottom of the stack which means that a widget added to the bottom most layer will appear in the top most layer. Is that correct? Or can one use rules to omit a layer?
2. Has anyone documented any obvious pitfalls to this approach?

It just seems like a very odd way to go about things, but perhaps just because we're not used to it.

Thanks,

Comment: There is actually a relatively close concept in Drupal.

Comment: I have very little experience with Drupal so it wouldn't help much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name can be confusing because it does sound like there would be some sort of z-index ordering or something.  However, layers' only job is to determine whether or not a shape gets rendered.  If a layer rule returns true, the shapes in that layer will be visible.  If a layer rule returns false, the shapes in that layer will not be rendered.  That's all there is to it.

This is really useful for authenticated/non-authenticated scenarios.  Also, since the layer rules are extensible, you can add your own complex scenarios.  Say for example, you want to have widgets on your site during work hours only.  You could build your own layer rule extension and create a layer for widgets called "office-hours-only".

Comment: Thanks Brandon. 
Shapes is another confusing bit of terminology. But I'll leave that for now.  
It's still difficult to compare this to something like DotNetNuke. 
Looking at the layers again after your explanation it still doesn't make sense. If I choose default and drop a HTML Widget onto one of the "Zones?" then I switch to Authenticated the HTML widget appears in there in the same zone with the option to move it to the current layer. This is why I assumed it's similar to Photoshop type layers. ??

Comment: I don't get the Photoshop analogy.  Maybe they are similar in some way, but I don't see it.  Zones dictate "where" something will be rendered while layers dictate "when/if" something will be rendered.  That's really all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks again Brandon. The PhotoShop analogy was used by someone else explaining layers the idea being that you can hide or show layers in a Photoshop file to reveal different areas of a design. So it sounds somewhat the same as you're describing. So does this mean that you only ever have a single layout file in Orchard (per theme that is)? I understand the part about zones collapsing if they have no content, but I'm just thinking about scenarios in some sites where you have a group of pages that are vastly different in layout than say the Home, Contact Us and About us pages.

Comment: There are a few ways I can think of to solve that problem depending on the case.  You should probably post a new question with specifics on that topic.

Comment: The widget admin screen has a feature that lets you turn the visibility of layers on and off, with the same eye icon. That's where the analogy comes from, but that's also where it stops.